# User_timing google analytics data not showing on analytics dashboard even if successfully fired from website

Tags: javascript, angular, google-analytics

I am working with angular and using the navigation_start and end events in app.component.ts to measure the timiing and then firing a simple page_view and timing event.Both data are sended to analytics as seen in network tab.Code is as follow:

app.component.ts

```
import { AuthService } from './core/services/auth.service';
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { BalakRoutes } from './core/constants/route.constant';
import { TimeTrackingService } from './shared/utils/time-tracking.service';

declare let gtag: Function;
@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line
  selector: 'body',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet> <ngx-ui-loader></ngx-ui-loader>'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  myAppUrl: string = '';
  private configLoadActionId: number;
  private navigationActionId: number;
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private timingService: TimeTrackingService
  ) {
    this.myAppUrl = '/';
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
      if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
        if (evt instanceof NavigationStart) {
          this.navigationActionId = this.timingService.startTracking(
            'navigation'
          );
        }

        return;
      } else {
        const result = this.timingService.stopTracking(this.navigationActionId);
        gtag('config', 'UA-176408533-1', {
          page_path: evt.urlAfterRedirects
        });
        gtag('event', 'timing_complete', {
          name: 'load',
          event_label: 'load : ' + evt.urlAfterRedirects,
          value: result.elapsed
        });
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

timingService works fine and returns proper values so I am not showing here.

[image: Network tab proof of data being sended]

[image: Proof from analytics]

**Note:** There is no issue that I am not able to see bcoz of some sampling issue.I can't see even after 48 hrs

Comment: It can depend on the volume of traffic and the frequency of sending hits of that type.

Comment: @MichelePisani my site is hosted but still we are developing it. there are 50 to 60 page views per day. Can you please give the answer how do it depends on traffic and frequency.Thank u in advance dear Michaele

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 'event_category' parameter instead 'name':

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events